# mysql query regex between 2 words to loop

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need a regex to use in the query `select * from table where field regex ***` in order to match the record only if my *"Gamma"* and *"Alpha"* are, at least in 1, of the same `;between;`

I have a text filed in table like:

```
... ;Model Alpha Beta Gamma; Model Hitch Gamma Alpha; Model Pi Alpha Gamma; ...
```

or (i can change structure if it is easier)

```
....
;Model Alpha Beta Gamma;
;Model Hitch Pi Alpha;
;Model Pi Alpha Gamma;
....
```

So i have different sentences (separeted by `;`) in the same field and I need a regex role that consider any sentence as a group in witch looking the presence of some words.

I m using a cms so i need change the query: changing the DB means months of work.

Comment: Why not just use ```LIKE```? IOW, ```WHERE field LIKE ";%Gama%;" OR field like ";%Alpha%;"```.

Comment: If you have semicolon separated values and you only want to extract certain substrings (individual qualifying values between semicolons), then you have a suboptimal database table structure.  Time to normalize and split the values up over multiple rows.  Smart design now means easier work later.  p.s. When posting a msyql question it provides greatest clarity to post your table structure and a few relevant sample rows.

Comment: @mickmackusa changed the post is clearer. 
Im in a cms, i cannot changed structure; only the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is select rows that have a field with a semi-colon-separated-value that has both `Alpha` & `Gamma` AND those two values can possibly be in any order respective to each other AND there can be other words between them.

So considering rows that have fields like this:

```
|field                                                            |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Beta Gamma;Model Hitch Pi Alpha;Model Pi Alpha Gamma |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Beta Gamma;Model Hitch Pi Alpha;Model Pi Gamma             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Beta Omega                                                 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Gamma                                                |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Pi Beta Gamma;Model Hitch Pi Gamma                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Hitch Gamma Sigma Sigma                                    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Zeta Tau Alpha;Model Alpha Xi Delta                        |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Epsilon Phi;Model Gamma Phi Alpha                    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Sigma Gamma Alpha; Model Lambda Lambda Lambda              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Beta Beta Phi; Model Hitch Lambda Pi; Model Phi Pi         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT field FROM `table` WHERE `field` REGEXP 'Alpha[^;]+Gamma|Gamma[^;]+Alpha'
```

To put these rows in the resultset:

```
|field                                                            |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Beta Gamma;Model Hitch Pi Alpha;Model Pi Alpha Gamma |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Gamma                                                |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Alpha Epsilon Phi;Model Gamma Phi Alpha                    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|Model Sigma Gamma Alpha; Model Lambda Lambda Lambda              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa, you were very usefull. 
I have undefined number of words, so if exist the possible to looking for random position of entire word (avoiding the combination all possibile combination), my request would be completely satisfy